# Using the definition of limit, prove $\frac{x+1}{x+2}\to 1$ as $x\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta, limits-without-lhopital

How can I show a limit using the mathematical definition? I always computed limits but never learned how to prove it.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{x+1}{x+2}=1$$

Comment: Do you want a proof according to the definition or one using L'Hospital or some other trick?

Comment: First write ${x+1\over x+2}=1-{1\over x+2}$. Now show that, given $\epsilon>0$, there is an $m$ so that $\Bigl| \Bigl(1-{1\over x+2}\Bigr)-1\Bigr|<\epsilon$ whenever $x>m$.

Answer (score 6):

When you say "mathematical definition", I am not sure if you wanted to prove the limit rigorously with an $\epsilon$ argument, but I'll just write it anyway:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Let $M=\frac 1{\epsilon}$. If $x > M$, then $$\left| \frac{x+1}{x+2}-1\right|=\left|\frac{-1}{x+2}\right|=\frac{1}{x+2}<\frac 1x<\frac 1M=\epsilon.$$

Answer (score 5):

$$\text{Hint: } \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x+1}{x+2} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x+2 - 1}{x+2} = 1 - \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x+2} = \space ...$$

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the top and bottom of the fraction by $x$ and get $\frac{1+\frac{1}{x}}{1+\frac{2}{x}}$.